# Accepting funding from a climate change denier

Tags: funding

Abstract: A professor in my department, who seems to be a climate change denier, is offering me funding for a project that is NOT related to climate change. Should I take it?

For my stipend at the my department, I have to teach a lot. This implies 12-15 hours of work per week for the next one year. It is a lot of time I could put into research/writing papers instead.

I have been offered funding to conduct research under a professor. The research question sounds interesting, is unrelated to climate science, and is probably going to lead to publications along with relieving me of teaching duties. However, the professor offering this funding says that sea levels are not rising at an accelerated rate.

Perhaps one extreme way of looking at this would be that he is a climate change denier. However, he did claim that he does not know about other indicators of climate change- he only pointed out that sea levels are not rising at an accelerated rate, which is a claim made by climate change proponents.

He said that NOAA data suggests this. However, on doing a simple google search, I found this article on the NOAA website- https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/sealevel.html

To quote from the article, "Yes, sea level is indeed rising at an increasing rate. Global sea level has been rising over the past century, and the rate has increased over recent decades."
Hence, his source of information also seems to be spurious. Should I accept funding from him? It seems to look good for my life and career in general. But should I compromise on my beliefs and take funding from him?-

Comment: Sorry, we cannot really tell you what to do. In general, in any workplace, you will have to work with people whose beliefs are the opposite of yours: it's up to you to decide whether to keep working with them or find another position in the hope of finding colleagues more aligned with your beliefs.

Comment: I will ask you a few questions. If he was religious, and you were not, would you accept? If you were religious, and he was not, would you accept? If he was gay, would you accept? If he was a fascist, would you accept? If he didn't appreciate Monet's painting, would you accept? If he thought that Twilight is a good movie, would you accept?

Comment: @corey979 Having and acting on repugnant beliefs that harm others is not the same as taste in movies.

Comment: The framing here seems reversed.  I mean, it sounds like _would_ accept this funding if not for the source's position on climate change, right?  So the null-decision seems to be to accept the funding, as that's what you'd otherwise do.  Then, the question would seem to be if you should then change your mind, and reject the funding, based on the source's position about climate change.  This is then a question that sounds pretty opinion-based if you don't further specify why you might want to do this; for example, are you thinking that accepting would promote a position you disagree with?

Comment: I'm also wondering how you think you're compromising your beliefs by taking funding from him. I don't think anyone would ever construe that as you agreeing with his views about climate change. And in general, keeping civil relations with all the weird people out there that believe weird stuff is the only way you're gonna reach them when you want to convince them of your way of seeing things.

Comment: *says that sea levels are not rising at an accelerated rate* vs. *rising at an increasing rate* --- For issues as impassioned as this, I think extra care needs to be taken to say exactly what is intended. To me, "rising at an accelerated rate" implies the third derivative of height is positive, while "rising at an increasing rate" implies the second derivative of the height is positive. It is certainly possible that the height could be rising at an increasing rate without rising at an accelerated rate.

Answer (score 11):

It is ultimately up to you. However, if you refuse to collaborate with people who have different political, religious, moral, etc. standards or opinions than you, you'll pretty soon find that you are missing too many exciting opportunities. The disagreement over a climate change is a relatively mild one as far as such things are concerned. You do not need to change your position and you can even try to convince your professor that you are right when you have some chat over a cup of coffee, but I wouldn't take the issue too far. After all, from his perspective, he offers a collaboration to a proponent of some crazy politicized hype and does it first. So I would meet an open hand with an open hand in this case, but, as I said, nobody but you can make the choice.

Answer (score 6):

A lot of people you will come across have ideas that you would consider screwy if you only knew of them. But you don't.

Unless the idea repels you in some way, note that if the money isn't, itself, tainted and you aren't asked to do something you consider wrong, then there is no real reason to turn it down.

If the money was coming from a Coal Baron, you might want to refuse it. Likewise if you think you are being compromised in some way.

But hopefully the work you do will have some positive impact on the world in spite of any ideas of the professor.

Answer (score 5):

You say that the research is "unrelated to climate science" but I'd want to distinguish between two rather different scenarios:

1. The professor's professional research program is entirely unrelated to his climate change positions.  For example, let's say this professor does Number Theory.
2. The professor's professional research program touches on issues related to climate change, but the particular project you're working on doesn't relate to this.  For example, this professor works on fluid dynamics including applications to atmospheric science, but this project is about the mathematical side.

In case 1 I think you should completely ignore this person's non-professional non-expert opinions, and go ahead and collaborate (assuming those non-professional opinions are along the lines of being a flat earther or ghost hunting, and aren't something like working for ISIS or having a confederate flag tattoo).

In case 2 I think you should avoid this collaboration because this professor's poor professional judgement may reflect poorly on you if people see that you're collaborating with someone who also publishes junk.

Comment: "aren't something like working for ISIS or having a confederate flag tattoo" There's a difference between actively supporting a group of terroristic murderers, and having regional pride and/or political beliefs you disagree with.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the project being unrelated to climate change, he isn't someone who has any influence over policy except by voting. Like most culture-war issues, climate-change denialism isn't about what it claims to be about, which is why he doesn't care what the facts are and wouldn't be able to articulate what he *would* regard as convincing evidence of anthropogenic climate change.

This is a matter of identity: he imagines that he is an independent-minded skeptic who doesn't subscribe to the liberal agenda. There's no way to make a dent in that by refusing his funding and it will only reinforce propaganda about the intolerant left. So take his money and if you want try to reason with him if he brings the subject up. But this is almost certainly going to be a losing battle.

Comment: They do say "never argue with a fool, people can't tell the difference"...

Comment: I downvoted this for _Like most culture-war issues, climate-change denialism isn't about what it claims to be about_. How would you even know? What would even make this sentence true or false? If what percentage of climate change deniers actually held their beliefs for some other reason? In what way is that different from any other opinion, belief or conviction people have?

Comment: @sgf I know this because (1) there have been studies showing it and (2) culture-war positions like ACC denialism are prima facie logically and scientifically indefensible, but make perfect sense from other points of view. It's true that people delude themselves all the time about why they believe something, but ACC denialism specifically purports to be about lack of evidence, which is nonsense.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning _there have been studies showing it_ [Citation needed] Also, if you think that _there's some studies showing that p_ leads to _We know that p_, you're wrong. There's studies showing that cigarettes don't cause harm. (2) Scientifically perhaps. Logically certainly not. But that's not the issue here. You could, for example, hold that Marxism is scientifically and logically indefensible without thereby assuming that Marxism isn't about what it claims to be about.

Comment: @sgf Fine. I should have said "I believe this" instead of "I know this," which is true about pretty much anyone about anything.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning But then you should change your answer to contain "I believe that climate-change denialism isn't about what it claims to be about." Also I'm still curious what that sentence means, and what you think climate-change denialism (and culture-war issues in general) actually is about.

Comment: I believe that academics should know the difference between "I believe" and "I know."

Comment: @shoover ElizabethHenning has a point that, ahem, knowing, the precise difference between "believing" and "knowing" isn't gonna help us out here - of course we can always only believe that we know something, never know that we know it. But still, for almost anything you want to believe, you'll find at least one study to corraborate it.

Comment: "will only reinforce *propaganda* about the intolerant left" I wish it were a pure propaganda! *he isn't someone who has any influence over policy except by voting.* If he is a reputable researcher, he may have some other options too. But you entirely miss the point anyway: the OP is concerned about his own integrity, not about the conversion of the professor into his faith...

Comment: I'm not sure if I see the connection between your first paragraph and the question.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning I believe on re-reading what I wrote that there's a misunderstanding. When I wrote "How would you even know? What would even make this sentence true or false?", I was less curious about "How did you come to have this knowledge" (which is what you answered in your comment), and more "Is that even knowledge one can have", because I have no idea what it's supposed to mean.

Comment: @sgf This should really all be in chat and I don't want to spend a lot of time on this, but I'll give a brief answer here: an easy example is "pro-life." The great majority of pro-lifers also oppose policies that demonstrably reduce the number of unplanned pregnancies. This obviously contradicts the claim that the primary concern is protecting the unborn. Other features of pro-life rhetoric, which are sometimes made explicit, indicate that the real concern is "family breakdown" and women's equality in the form of women having sex without marriage and without the intention to become mothers.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning That seems like a totally different case. It's basically about the nomenclature, and we'll all agree that "pro-lifers" aren't characterized by their belief that life is a good thing, but by their belief that abortions are horrible. But that's an ethical judgment, and once you go into ethics, you get into "is this the primary goal, or is it secondary to another, and if two secondary goals clash, how do I pick and choose". (Of course, pro-lifers often being religious, they wouldn't usually claim that preventing abortions is their primary goal.) Climate-change-denialism is not

Comment: about ethics, it's about disbelieving a certain set of scientific results. I see how you could be a pro-lifer, even if your primary concern isn't preventing abortions (what you seem to call "not being really about pro-life." But I don't think that anyone even expects a climate change denier to have climate change denialism as their primary concern, it's just one of their beliefs about the world.

Comment: (That there are political groups that have an interest in promoting climate change denialism which isn't that they actually don't believe in it doesn't really factor into how to treat individuals that, at least consciously, reject climate change in good faith.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should consider the possibility that his claim about sea levels is true.

He is a math professor, who makes this claim and says he does not know about other indicators of climate change. Based on that, I would guess that he knows a lot more about sea levels than you, and a lot more than can be found from a simple google search and a single short article on the NOAA website. Maybe he has looked at the actual data.

If you want to find out, you could ask the professor, or look for proper scientific articles about whether the rise is accelerating, or get the data and see for yourself.

Comment: I guess the point is that he claims NOAA data is what clearly states that sea levels are not rising. However, the NOAA website clearly states that sea levels are indeed rising. Hence, unless NOAA is contradicting its own data, it is likely that the sea levels are indeed rising

Comment: I agree some clarification on the professor's statement is needed. There is a difference between an informed opinion that a particular methodology is flawed and a fact-denying "skeptic" who refuses to accept well-established results.